# What is Buck Strickland referring to in this joke?

Tags: king-of-the-hill

In Season 4 Episode 19, *Hank's Bad Hair Day*, Hank walks into work with bleached, spiked hair. Buck walks in a moment later and sees him, saying:

**Good God Hank, you look like that fella that killed that other fella!**

[image]

What does this mean? I have searched but between Reddit, KotH forums, and (cringe) Yahoo Answers, there doesn't seem to be a clear consensus. Buck is notoriously ridiculous with his euphemisms and and pop culture references, so I've even looked for a bleached, spikey haired *female* murderer, but I can't find anyone that makes sense.

Who is Buck saying Hank looks like?

Comment: I think the vagueness is intentional and he is simply stereotyping people who have bleached spikey hair as delinquents and murderers like you'd see on tv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a vague joke, due to playing on the way that Buck is very much out-of-touch with social norms and typical behaviours -- just as @sanpaco suggested.

Or it could be a reference to this (the episode is from 1999, but this is from 1986, closer to Buck's "prime", which he never really evolved from):
http://gilmermirror.com/bookmark/14655941-Largest-manhunt-in-Texas-happened-25-years-ago

[image]